# Location of 2019 Ford Fusion door code

Tags: ford, code

Bought a used Fusion hybrid.  Door code unknown.  Some web pages say it is printed on a module inside the driver’s door.  Others say the module is in the cargo compartment.  If someone can tell me which is correct, I can save the risk of pulling the wrong one first.

**Update**:  I can now confirm ‘narkeleptk’ is correct.  The label on mine has CDJ instead of CDM. Unfortunately, trying lots of different camera angles, a body part hides the code every time.  Here’s the best one I was able to get.
[image]

**Another update**: I took a picture from the side, and got an unreadable angle on the code.  But I was able to distort the image with a graphic editor to make the code readable.  YAY!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module that contains the door code data is the SJB on older modules and BCM on newer models. Usually located under drivers area. Some people will just call it a fuse box.

Edit, I just checked a few fusion sjbs/bcms I have laying around the shop and I do not see any with the door codes printed on the older ones.

I do believe I see it on the newer models however so you might just be in luck.

[image: keycode]

[image: bcm]

Comment: Oops, I thought I had put “2019” in there.  Several web pages say it’s on a label on the RAP behind a panel in the cargo compartment.  Others say it’s on a label on a module inside the driver’s door.  And I can display it on the dashboard IF I have TWO remotes.

Comment: Looks like it is labeled on the newer bcms- I'll edit in an image for you.

Comment: According to the owner’s manual, the fuses on this one are on a very different layout, and I find nothing like that behind that panel.  I think I’ll go ahead and pay the dealers ridiculous price.

Comment: that box is from a 2019. Not sure what the dealer charges but I usually do it for free when making keys for people. You may want to call a few local locksmiths to see what they might charge you to pull it. I reckon a decent price for MOBILE service to you and pulling the code would be max $60.

Comment: Dealer price is actually reasonable—$60.  I got a little mixed up, thinking of the $400 they said for second remote key.  BUT, if the code is readable on a label somewhere, telling me they have to make an appointment and that it takes an hour to read it out of the computer is a bit weird.  (And if I buy the extra remote, it allows me to read the door key in less than a minute.)

Comment: I think the picture in the owner's manual might be just part of the BCM, the part with the actual fuses.

Comment: Now confirmed that the BCM is WAY up inside the dashboard, and to get to the label near the top, I'll need a camera on a stick or disassemble the dashboard.  To change a fuse, I'll need a mini-robot or a disassembly.

Comment: You should be able to reach the fuses just under the drivers dash without doing too much. Removing the whole bcm is a bit of a pain tho because its such a tight fit in there. The label you need to read is on the backside so like you said, you'd prob need to remove it or get a camera back there. Its not all that bad if your used to pulling modules but if thats not yoru thing its an easy $60 to spend to save yourself the headache.

Comment: Without removing part of the dash, I can reach SOME of the fuses, but can’t see it well enough to know which is which.  The label is similar to the one in the picture of the whole module, but what’s around it prevents me from getting a picture of more than half of it.  It does not look like the picture of just the label and does not seem to have the code on it.  Does “on the backside” mean the side _away_ from the fuses?